# Guacamole audio is not working with pulseaudio

Tags: networking, sound, pulseaudio

I am trying to broadcast audio/video from pc to smart-tv
the best solution I found was guacamole+tigerVNC+Pulseaudio
video is fine but no audio

After debugging for days I am able to see in wireshark tcp packets between guacamole and pulseaudio but tcp stream stops and I don't hear anything in my tv "or any other device".

Here is the log from guacamole service which states every thing is okay.

```
sudo systemctl status guacd.service 
● guacd.service - LSB: Guacamole proxy daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/guacd; generated)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-10-18 02:19:53 CEST; 17min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 2285 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/guacd start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 19 (limit: 19033)
     Memory: 38.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/guacd.service
             ├─ 2319 /usr/local/sbin/guacd -p /var/run/guacd.pid
             ├─ 4381 /usr/local/sbin/guacd -p /var/run/guacd.pid
             └─13530 /usr/local/sbin/guacd -p /var/run/guacd.pid

Okt 18 02:37:41 andrew guacd[13530]:   Least significant byte first in each pixel.
Okt 18 02:37:41 andrew guacd[13530]:   TRUE colour: max red 255 green 255 blue 255, shift red 16 green 8 blue 0
Okt 18 02:37:41 andrew guacd[13530]: Connecting to PulseAudio...
Okt 18 02:37:41 andrew guacd[13530]: Authorizing PulseAudio connection...
Okt 18 02:37:41 andrew guacd[13530]: Sending client name...
Okt 18 02:37:41 andrew guacd[13530]: PulseAudio now ready
Okt 18 02:37:41 andrew guacd[13530]: Will use default sink: "alsa_output.pci-0000_0b_00.4.analog-stereo"
Okt 18 02:37:41 andrew guacd[13530]: Starting streaming from "Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo"
Okt 18 02:37:41 andrew guacd[13530]: PulseAudio stream being created...
Okt 18 02:37:41 andrew guacd[13530]: PulseAudio stream now ready
```

I followed this [guacamole guideline](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html) and below is a screenshot of wireshark traffic between guacamole and pulseaudio using port 4713 in server PC but it stops quickly without any clear issues.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Knowing that there are quite a few of "media server" solutions, both free and commercial, supported by any modern smart TV this question seems SURREAL!!

Comment: @ChanganAuto It could be helpful if you'd share some of those solutions

Comment: @Nmath miniDLNA? home-media-server? Emby? Kodi? Plex?... Even Ubuntu's native multimedia sharing? All are common knowledge. More at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for the apps advice. But I need generic screen sharing connection+control not media server